# check on my website is user fan of my facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to make some facebook lightbox e.g. if some user come to my site and if is not fan of my FB page i want to show them lightbox with FB like button and if is already fan nothing happens. How to can I do it?

Comment: By having them connect to your app first, asking permission to read their likes … and then check if your page is among them.

Comment: I assumed...only that way :) simple information require all that big procedure :/. I thought if i embed like box to site and if like box can figured out is it page liked or not probably users can do it that trick.
if I had visitor ID i can make FQL etc...

Comment: The “big procedure” is there for privacy reasons. If a user has not connected to an app, the app has no business knowing who they are, what they liked, etc.

Comment: @CBroe, is it imortant to create application to check user like my page??? is it possible to do it with javascript in simple html site?

Comment: Yes, it’s possible with JavaScript client-side using the JS SDK. But you’ll need to create an app anyway.